# Switching between minified code and normal code depending on environment?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify

Currently using grunt to minify all of my js files. I have a php script in my html that checks the url and decides whether to include one big minified javascript file or all of the regular javascript files. This is annoying because I have all of the files listed in two places; once in the grunt file and once in the switch statement in my php script. If someone on the team adds a new file to one but not the other, bad things happen. Is there an easier more efficient way to go about switching between the two? We want it so that our production server uses the minified code and our local dev environments use the un-minified code.

Comment: Have you explored adding multiple tasks or multitasks with targets? http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks

Comment: I use multiple tasks for concatenating/minififying but I am not familiar with targets. I'll look into it.